# Add an exception to the regular expression

Tags: php

There is a regular expression:

```
(?:\S*)
```

How do I add the exception to the characters [ and ]

I tried to add:

```
(?:\S*!\[!\])
```

But this design does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should work (nothing to test against):

```
(?:[^\s\[\]]*)
```